# Bug in CSS 2.1 Table spec for computing column widths?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

The [Tables section in the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/tables.html#auto-table-layout) reads:

> If the 'table' or 'inline-table' element has 'width: auto', the used
>   width is the greater of the table's containing block width, CAPMIN,
>   and MIN. However, if **either CAPMIN or** the maximum width required
>   by the columns plus cell spacing or borders (MAX) **is** less than that of
>   the containing block, use max(MAX, CAPMIN).

I believe this may be an error, and that it should read:

> If the 'table' or 'inline-table' element has 'width: auto', the used
>   width is the greater of the table's containing block width, CAPMIN,
>   and MIN. However, if **both CAPMIN and** the maximum width required by
>   the columns plus cell spacing or borders (MAX) **are** less than that of
>   the containing block, use max(MAX, CAPMIN).

The reason is that CAPMIN is the minimum width of a caption. If we disregard the effect of CAPMIN, then the spec correctly uses the maximum width of all the columns when that width is less than the containing block width. But introducing the caption minimum width in the way the spec is worded causes the maximum width of the columns to be short-circuited when CAPMIN alone is less than the width of the containing block.

A web search also turned up [this link](http://momdo.s35.xrea.com/web-html-test/spec/CSS21/changes.html) which shows that the CAPMIN conditions were added later; perhaps the error was introduced at this point.

Is this analysis accurate?

Comment: Is the error in the behavior of the browsers? is it a wording/grammatical error?

Comment: I believe that browsers implement the corrected wording I've suggested above. I'm asking in this question whether the suggested correction is in fact correct.

Comment: In that case. You are wrong. The specifications *have* to be accurate, any behavior outside of the specifications are non-compliant, by definition.

Comment: No, the spec includes a list of [errata](http://www.w3.org/Style/css2-updates/REC-CSS2-20110607-errata.html) found to date. It is not frozen in that sense.

Comment: If you believe this is a bug, the best thing to do is submit it to the relevant browser bug trackers so they can implement a fix.

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment, browsers do the right thing. I believe this is a bug in the wording of the spec.